# google translate misses up the coding of my file

Tags: localization, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

i am trying to use google translate for localization of an XML file, it has near 350K lines, but some of them contain coding for in-game font size and color, like so:

```
<replacement>&lt;p horizontalalignment="center"&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;image enablescale="false" imagesetpath="00015590.InterD_Jeryoung_3"/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;image enablescale="true" imagesetpath="00015590.Tag_Dungeon_Six_Superior" scalerate="1.5"/&gt;&lt;image enablescale="true" imagesetpath="00015590.Tag_Dungeon_Four_Superior" scalerate="1.5"/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;image enablescale="true" imagesetpath="00009499.Field_Boss" scalerate="1.4"/&gt;Хмельной лик&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;Уничтожить зараженных насекомых&lt;br/&gt;возле мест обитания их королевы。&lt;br/&gt;</replacement>
```

now for god knows what reason, google translate alters that code in the process of translation into some unacceptable coding, like so:

```
<replacement> <p horizontalalignment="center"> <br/> <image enablescale="false" imagesetpath="00015590.InterD_Jeryoung_3"/> <br/> <image enablescale = "true "imagesetpath =" 00015590.Tag_Dungeon_Six_Superior "scalerate =" 1.5 "/> <image enablescale="true" imagesetpath="00015590.Tag_Dungeon_Four_Superior" scalerate="1.5"/> <br/> <image enablescale = "true" imagesetpath = "00009499.Field_Boss" scalerate = "1.4" /> Intoxicated face <br/> <br/> </ p> Destroy infected insects <br/> habitats near their queen. <br/> </ replacement>
```

is there any way to avoid that, why is it happening exactly? anyhelp is appreciated on that matter,thanks

**EDIT** : i am also looking for a way to input my text and have it out in the same exact language with only the coding mishaps changing, so i can isolate those,build a comparison table and then use that to fix the errors after the actual translation is done, but i don't see a way for selecting the same language as input AND output in google translate, it always forces me choose a different one in input or output, kind of makes sense but if there is a way to do that, i might be able to work around it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not feed Google translate with your Xml file, as far as I know it doesn't understand Xml.

Extract the text from the Xml file.

Feed the text to translate.

Transform the text back to Xml.

You could simply transform the Xml to a text document with a single line per Xml element so it would be easier to turn it back into Xml.

**More detail**

According to the [Toolkit](http://translate.google.com/toolkit/docupload?hl=en) you can upload:

```
HTML (.HTML)
Microsoft Word (.DOC/.DOCX)
OpenDocument Text (.ODT)
Plain Text (.TXT)
Rich Text (.RTF)
Wikipedia URLs
```

And a couple of extras such as JSON. So no Xml.

The best way I see is to transform your Xml document into one of these types (I would probably use JSON) and transform it is such a way that it can easily be transformed back again by using either position (1 line in the text file is the first element in the Xml document) or by an id (add the Id or position of the element in the xml hierarchy to the JSON element)

My guess is that the toolkit recognizes the html tags in the xml and escapes them. So another option might be to un-escape the `&gt;` to `>` and `&lt` to `<`

Comment: that's exactly what i did with the line i posted as an example up there, and when i translated the whole thing it was in text form and not in xml form..
no matter what the form i feed google translate, the result is the same, it always changes the code in the way i posted.

Comment: Do NOT pass html encoded text either. Just plain english. EXTRACT the English text first

Comment: first off, i want to extract the Russian text (to be translated to English) and second..how do you suggest i do that?! i mean i can't do it manually in 350,000 lines! and if i manage to somehow pull that off, how can i re-merge it into it's original coded format in the correct position after the translation is done?
any ideas are appreciated..

Comment: @user3658890 - I added to my answer

Comment: the XML document is just a bunch of lines in succession, there is nothing special to it, and when i do a copy/paste of the whole file into a text file (.txt), i have no problem at all with the format..
like i said, when i first uploaded the file, it was in ".txt" format and not xml!
now i didn't get the "un-escape" part..i really don't know what that means, please elaborate.

Comment: The format of the file is not determined by the extension of the file name but by its content. The toolkit 'recognizes' the format by looking at the content and thinks it is HTML. For safety (to keep the HTML-tags) it translates the angle brackets to &gt; and &lt; and then processes the text. Again: you are giving a document to the toolkit in an unsupported format so anything can go wrong.

Comment: thanks, and i am sorry for my ignorance..it's my first time dealing with such a problem as this is not exactly "my area of expertise" :)
anyway, i will look into this "JSON" format and see what i can do..i guess i will have to post another question if i had problems with that (seeing that it will be the first time dealing with such file) and i have already troubled you enough with this question :)